# Android App Creation to stream music from an online radio station

Tags: android

hey guys first time post and first time app trying to create an application that will stream music from an online radio station -

I have followed this link [How to play shoutcast streaming in android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294989/how-to-play-shoutcast-streaming-in-android-2-2)

but its errored out on

```
@override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.java);
```

and I cant see why can some one give me some education so to speak :) creating it on Build: v22.0.0-675183

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Just a quick fyi, R.java is usually a generated file. It should not be edited and contains id's for everything in your project. Do you have an XML layout that the activity is supposed to be referencing?

Comment: Please follow (and learn/understand) a little more closely.  From the link you gave - `setContentView(R.layout.main);`